# Vuelidate how to conditionally disable submit button

Tags: vuejs2, vuelidate

How can I conditionally disable the submit button of my Vuelidate form if all the fields don't meet the required criteria?

I tried the below but `:disabled` will only accept the word disabled in there.

```html
<form>
  <ol>
    <li class="inputQuestion" v-bind:class="{ 'error': $v.user.username.$error }">
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input v-model.trim="user.username" @input="$v.user.username.$touch()" />
    </li>
    <li class="inputQuestion" v-bind:class="{ 'error': $v.user.password.$error }">
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input v-model.trim="user.password" @input="$v.user.password.$touch()" />
    </li>

    <li class="submission">
      <button @click.prevent="submitForm" :disabled="$v.form.valid()">Sign In</button>
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, you are binding `disabled` to the value returned by `$v.form.valid()`, which will only be run once when the component's template is rendered and won't change after that point.

From the [Vuelidate documentation](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/#sub-form-submission), it looks like you are provided a `$invalid` property for the form model which:

> Indicates the state of validation for given model. becomes true when any of it's child validators specified in options returns a falsy value. In case of validation groups, all grouped validators are considered.

Use that instead:

```
<button @click.prevent="submitForm" :disabled="$v.form.$invalid">
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to disable/enable the submit button with vuelidate:

`<button @click.prevent="submitForm" :disabled="$v.$anyError">`